# How to Retweet as a Quote with custom message in Ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter, quote

How to Retweet as a Quote with custom message in Ruby
like tweeting as a quote with custom message.

Example: "XYZ Message {Quote Tweet Retweet}"

It is currently simply retweeting the tweet without message

[Like in the image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDHrp.png)

Here is my code:

```
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "x"
  config.consumer_secret     = "x"
  config.access_token        = "x"
  config.access_token_secret = "x"
end

def run(client)
  retweetKeyword = "abc"

  while true
     re = client.search(retweetKeyword).first.id
     client.retweet(re);
     puts "Retweet: #{re} #{Time.now}";
     sleep(30); #Every five minutes
  end
end

run(client);
```

Comment: Instead of `while true ... end` consider `loop do ... end` which is made specifically for that purpose.

Comment: A quote is just a tweet with a link to another tweet.

Comment: i am new into ruby can anyone plz write 1-2 line sample code how to implement this. thanks

Comment: just checked out https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/Update.md

Post an update in reply to another tweet.

client.update("I'm tweeting with @gem!", in_reply_to_status_id: 402712877960019968)

but I am storing tweet number in a variable name "re" and when i add re in place of 4027... number gets error no reply..

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Hootsuit that how it retweets then you'll see that it just tweet the Tweet Url that you want to Quote and it quotes that.

To Quote a Tweet with a Custom Message, you would do something like this,

```
"Quote message" Tweet Url  like this 
https://twitter.com/cowan_rebs/status/983310177343627264
```

and it would quote the tweet with the custom message.

Hope that answers the question.